# Custom Object limit count

Tags: custom-object, installedpackage

We currently have some Installed Packages whose components do count towards our limits. There are some which have quite a bit of custom objects and I would like to get rid of them if possible.

What determines if an Installed Package's components do count towards your limits ? I know it's only the Installed Packages who have the "Limit" checked in the Installed Packages list view - but what determines that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package that does not count towards limits was created by an ISV *and* has passed a Security Review. In other words, it's basically a checkbox that the Security Review Team checks on your package after deeming your package not-dangerous. Packages that do not go through a Security Review count towards the limits normally. You can read more about it on [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HEXq).

Comment: Interesting Brian, I thought and read that managed package objects don't count against the org limits.

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy Only specially marked managed packages. I have a few packages laying around here somewhere which are managed, but if you installed them, would count against your limits. Also, there's other limits besides just object and field limits that this feature controls, such as the 3,000,000 Apex Code character limit, and so on. Being an ISV/Partner has its benefits.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thank you for the link to Aloha apps. That was interesting. So, I'd like to have this app's custom objects not count against my limit. Should I ask him to go through a Security Review ? If so, how would he go about doing that ? Is it feasible request on my part ? Also - I guess they'd need to become an ISV (....forget what it stands for....?). Is that big demand on our part as well ?

Comment: @Zoom_v I don't know the specifics on becoming an ISV, but I know there's minimum requirements and a contract you have to sign. As for the app itself, if you never intend to sell it, you could make it a free app, which would make the Security Review free for it; if you wanted to publicly list it and charge for it, it's 2700 USD for the first year, 300 USD afterwards. And more contracts. You would have to determine for yourself if its worth trying to go through the process (initial setup may take as long as 3 months...).

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thank you so much for your input. You're always a great help. FTR - It's not me who wrote this app - it's an external vendor. But the app is taking up FIFTY custom objects in our limit ! I will present them with the information you provide here and ask them to see if they could follow this process to make their app not count against our limit. Thanks again.

Comment: For anyone coming across this - what specifically needs to happen is that Managed Package needs to be `Aloha enabled` on SF side. SF support only does that after a Security Review, however we hit a situation where the SecReview was passed, but Aloha enablement did not happen so reviewed app still counted towards limits. You would need to raise a support ticket to DevSecOps team at Salesforce to rectify this.

Answer (score 3):

The custom objects that are contained in a managed package that’s publicly posted on the AppExchange don’t count against the limits for your Salesforce edition. At the same time, an org can’t have more than 2,000 custom objects, regardless of the source or namespace of those objects. Soft-deleted custom objects and their data count against your limits.

Reference: [Salesforce Features & Edition Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_general.htm&type=5)